# Making an iFrame responsive to height of it's content (PHPBB)

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, opencart, phpbb3

I am trying to embed a forum into my cart software (Opencart) as I believe it will help greatly in making the website more social, the only method I currently know of to accomplish this is by using a custom page with an iFrame to show the forum.

The website homepage is https://heroesofgc.com/index.php?route=common/home and the iFrame is currently on https://heroesofgc.com/forum2 (not linked in menu yet due to the bugs).

I have browsed through many options here on this site but with all of them I have encountered some very strange behavior with the iFrame. The iFrame is fluctuating between resizing and not resizing, it will for a few hours resize properly and then for another few hours simply refuse to resize. 
This is not specific to any browser as I have tried on Safari, Firefox, Chrome, Edge, and Internet explorer - and while some of them resize, some of them don't but a few hours later the ones that didn't resize are resizing and vice versa. It shows no noticeable pattern, it just sometimes works and sometimes doesn't.

Here's what I am currently doing: 1) I'm using PHPBB 2) In the "header.tpl" for the opencart theme I am using I have added the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getDocHeight(doc) {
    doc = doc || document;
    // stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/
    var body = doc.body, html = doc.documentElement;
    var height = Math.max( body.scrollHeight, body.offsetHeight, 
        html.clientHeight, html.scrollHeight, html.offsetHeight );
    return height;
}

function setIframeHeight(id) {
    var ifrm = document.getElementById(id);
    var doc = ifrm.contentDocument? ifrm.contentDocument: 
        ifrm.contentWindow.document;
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ifrm.style.height = "10px"; // reset to minimal height ...
    // IE opt. for bing/msn needs a bit added or scrollbar appears
    ifrm.style.height = getDocHeight( doc ) + 4 + "px";
    ifrm.style.visibility = 'visible';
}

document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() { // Adjust the Id accordingly
    setIframeHeight(this.id);
}
</script>
```

3) Then on the page, I am using the following iFrame code:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" id="ifrm" onload="setIframeHeight(this.id)" src="https://www.heroesofgc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&amp;t=1" width="100%">
```

Would anyone know of a cause for this weird behavior, or better yet a fix for it?

The ability to use a reliable and compatible iFrame could be a big asset for other small business including myself, as the alternative would require a substantial investment of both time and money.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though the element can't be found on page load.

Try placing

```
document.getElementById('ifrm').onload = function() { // Adjust the Id accordingly
    setIframeHeight(this.id);
}
```

at the end of the page so that the iFrame ID exists before being called.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Which page should this be added to? It is currently on the Header.tpl of Opencart as it is the only relevant place I could find, what location would be better for this?

Comment: Pop it in footer.tpl in OpenCart?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Just checked. Looks like the code is still in the header.

Comment: I reverted after testing. I didn't want to lose track of my edits.

Answer (score 0):

Bit weird answering my own question, but I managed to find a solution so I'll post the results here.

I found a responsive iFrame that works on the following page:
https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer

As I am using Opencart with a PHPbb3 forum it was (for me at least) a little difficult to find the correct files to edit, after a bit of fiddling I managed to get it working. Please note that these instructions are specific to Opencart and PHPBB3 respectively, and may be considered redundant to more advanced users.

Here's what you do:
1) On the above page download the zip file and extract it
2) Using FTP upload the 'iframeResizer.min.js' and the 'iframeResizer.map' (the .map file may not be necessary, but this is what I did) to your opencart/catalog/view/javascript folder.
3) Using Ftp upload the 'iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js', and 'iframeResizer.contentWindow.map' files to a folder in your PHPbb3 installation (I placed it in my style's /template folder).

4) In Opencart's installation, edit the 'header.php' file in the catalog/controller/common folder. Add the following code (I added mine just before the '$this->data['base'] = $server;' line:

```
$this->document->addScript('catalog/view/javascript/iframeResizer.min.js');
```

5) In PHPBB's installation, find the 'overal_header' file inside the template folder of the style you are using. Add the following code just after the :

```
<script src="path-to-your-content-window-resizer/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js"></script>
```

With that your basically set up to use the iFrame's on any page in opencart to show your forum pages and content. Use the iFrame structure given on the above page and twek it to your liking.